# feign.RetryableException Connection refused executing ... Spring Boot + Feign + Docker Compose

Tags: spring, docker-compose

I'm facing this issue when trying to use a microservice in docker (this doesn't happen in local).

> An exception occurred in RetryableException, in the line -2:
> Connection refused executing GET http://localhost:8082/api/car/findAll

this is my **docker-compose** file

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  people:
    build:
      context: peoplems
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    networks:
      - host
  vehicles:
    build:
      context: vehiclesms
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
    networks:
      - host
  api:
    build:
      context: apigateway
      dockerfile: Dockefile
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - host
networks:
  host:
    driver: bridge
```

The services are running

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I was trying to call "localhost" using feignclient

`url = http://localhost:8081/api/car`

So, when the app was 'deployed' in docker, docker wouldn't find the localhost address. I had to change "localhost" by the name of the container where the service was deployed: parking-people-1. My new url in feignclient is now

`url = http://parking-people-1:8081/api/car`

and it works.

NOTE: with this solution, you don't have to create a new network anymore. (at least in this case.)

I hope this could be useful for someone.